# Ant unable to detect External Libraries?

Tags: java, ant, build, jar

I am trying to follow [this Ant guide](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html), and I am getting errors in the section where I am trying to add the external library of log4j. As per the guide's instructions, I have downloaded the appropriate [this log4j jar](http://www.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/1.2.16/) and placed it into my lib library. I also tried just unpacking the jar file directly into the lib folder.

The error is, although I have already imported the necessary libraries and pointed Ant to is in my build.xml, it is unable to find it.

```
error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist ...
error: could not find symbol BasicConfigurator.configure(); ...
                             ^
```

Here is my build.xml file, which is pretty much copy and pasted from the example (minus the "oata" package name:

```
<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="HelloWorld"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

Comment: Check if this works for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22284104/2549021

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried just unpacking the jar file directly into the lib
>   folder.

Unpacking a JAR is utterly wrong.  *Never* do that.

The file your link refers to is a ZIP file, not a JAR.  It has the log4j-1.2.16.jar inside it.  If you open that, you'll see the BasicConfigurator.class in the org.apache.log4j package.

Comment: duffymo, thanks for the reply. The lib folder is inside my project folder, referred to by lib.dir property. And I get this error when during the "compile" stage. The current order is _clean->compile->jar->run_ i believe

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to import the library directly?

```
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="log4j.jar"/>
</path>
```

And remember the path has to be set from the build.xml.