# Unable to run JAR through command line or double click

Tags: java, ant, command-line, jar, jdeveloper

I was following [Ant tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) and wrote a simple program for log4j.But when I am trying to run the JAR by command line I am unable to do so.

Now I am unable to even guess what is the problem.

- No error is coming up when running JAR via the command line but log file is not updating
- Log file is updated when app ran in JDeveloper
- Log file is updated when JAR is ran via Ant script
- I have already added log4j.properties inside the JAR
- I have added classpath in commandline

**About the JAR** (LoggingTestApp.jar)

META-INF -> MANIFEST.mf

pack ->Mainn.class

log4j.properties

**MANIFEST.MF**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 19.1-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: pack.Mainn
```

**The pack.Mainn class**

```
package pack;

import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Mainn {
    public Mainn() {
        super();
    }
    String className = this.getClass().getName();

    void logTest() {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(className);
        System.out.println("Logging started");
        log.debug(this.className + "Hello this is an debug message");
        log.info(this.className + "Hello this is an info message");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Main started");
        Mainn a = new Mainn();
        a.logTest();
    }
}
```

**Ant build script**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="LoggingTestApp" basedir="." default="main">
    <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
    <property name="lib.dir"     value="lib"/>

    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class"  value="pack.Mainn"/>

    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
        <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}" excludes="**/*.java"/>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

Initially some errors of Mainn class not found were coming but I was able to take care of that by looking up.

Now there is one thing that I have been unable to do. I tried the following command to run it but there was some problem due to classpath.

**Running directly**

```
java -jar ./LoggingTestApp.jar

Main started
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
        at pack.Mainn.logTest(Unknown Source)
        at pack.Mainn.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

I looked up and found that Running with jar as part of classpath solved the problem for everybody. When **I ran the following command no error came up but the log did not update**.

```
java -cp I:\Study\Codes\_JDeveloper\LoggingTestApp\Client\lib\log4j1.2.13.jar;.\LoggingTestApp.jar pack.Mainn
```

No error but just

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "server" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

Now I don't know what to look for. There's no error but using command line to run the JAR is not working at all.

Comment: What does the manifest declare as the jarfile's main entry class?

Comment: @keshlam Added MANIFEST.MF also. The Main-file is 'pack.Mainn'.

Comment: Looks to me as if it can't find the Apache log dependency.  That jar is also needed in the class path when executing.

Comment: @TeresaCarrigan the second command also. I ran it two times. The first time it gave that error so I added the second command which has `log4j` jar in the path

Comment: Does the `java -cp` command run your program or not? Do you want this command to work, or the `java -jar` command?

Comment: @JBNizet I don't care which command I use. I want to run the JAR through the command line. I tried both (and many others which I haven't mentioned here) but the log did not update by either. The output is as shown. FOr `-cp` command I am getting that output containing how to use Java.

Comment: The `java -cp` command should work fine, provided that the paths are correct. I don't understand why you get the usage message. Try running it without the `-cp` option at all (you should get an exception because the main class can't be found). Then with only your jar file in the -cp option (you should get an exception because log4j classes can't be found).

Comment: @JBNizet Yeah it should work fine or it should throw error. But it doing neither and just giving me Java usage. That usage should be shown only when I am using java command incorrectly. I don't understand why it is showing me that.

Comment: As I said, try just using `java`, then `java -version`, then `java pack.Mainn`, etc. until you find what in the command causes the problem. Are you running this command inside a cygwin or git bash shell, or in the standard Windows command line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49357/discussion-between-aseem-bansal-and-jb-nizet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try packing the `log4j` library along with your JAR file

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
        </manifest>
        <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="I:/Study/Codes/_JDeveloper/LoggingTestApp/Client/lib/log4j1.2.13.jar"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: java doesn't add jar files inside jar files to the classpath.

Comment: @JBNizet: Obviously Java doesn't add jar files inside jar files to the classpath but when creating the JAR files one can pack the required libraries in the same JAR file and define the class path in the `manifest`, thus making the required library available at runtime without explicitly defining the library path using `-cp` option. Please look at the updated answer. And this has always worked for me.

Comment: No. The Class-Path manifest entry looks for jars **outside** of the main jar file. Not inside. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html.

Comment: Once I have created the JAR file using the script mentioned above, the  content(packages and classes) of log4j JAR file get extracted into the main jar file, so it is not a JAR file anymore, thus behaving in the same manner as of other packages and classes. If I would have liked log4j to be packed as a JAR file I would have used `jar-in-jar loader` for that purpose. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the above packaged the log4j jar itself inside the main jar. I wouldn't recommend using fat jars anyway. If everybody  did that, can you imagine the number of incompatible copies of the log4j classes we would have in the classpath? There's really nothing wrong in using the standard technique, looking for jars outside the main jar file.

Comment: I totally agree with you on putting the library JAR files outside the main JAR. However, this was just a quick way to avoid `-cp` option while testing and running the JAR files again and again. On other note, if we started packing the library JAR files inside the main JAR, the size of the main JAR will also increase abrupty and undesirably - which we don't want any way.

Comment: You could use the Class-Path manifest entry to reference the log4j jar file outside of the main jar file. That would allow using java -jar, without needing a fat jar containing the log4j classes in addition to the application classes.

Comment: @JBNizet I had actually tried changing class-path also. When I made it  as <path-to-log4j-jar> then it wasn't able to find `pack.Mainn`. Then I used `%classpath%;<path-to-log4j-jar>` and it started giving illegal argument exception. Although it shouldn't be doing so. Any ideas why? In cmd I ran `java -jar ./LoggingTestApp.jar`